# excel multiplication result not correct

Tags: excel

i'm new in excel - i have 3 cells B18:B20 with 3 integer value which get them average in another cell(c18) with average function(=AVERAGE(B18:B20)). now when i want to use the c:18 value to multiplication with a cell like h8 the result is not correct.

```
example:
b18=170
b19=169
b20=173
c18=average(b18:b20) = 171
c8=18.5
e18=c18*c8 = 315733(wrong) the result must be 316350
when i use 171 without average formula the result is ok
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xFdS.png)

Comment: Your numbers are off.  `171 * 18.5 ~ 3163.5`, not `316350`

Comment: The average of 170,169 and 173 is approx. 171 not exact 171. hence the DIFFERENCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ROUND()` function:

```
e18 = ROUND(c18, 0) * c8
```

Your current result is not "wrong" insofar as it comes from the correct average of the three numbers to several decimal places.  If you want to use what you see, then use `ROUND()` to 0 digits.

By the way, the data in your original problem are off as I mentioned in the comment, though this does not change the answer.